# Formula of Google Sheet to compute the rest of 24 hour duration from a timestamp?

Tags: time, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In the cell `A2`, there is the timestamp, say 21:35, I'd like to calculate the remaining time to midnight. 
It's essentially, 24 hours minus 21:35. But I want to have a formula for the calculation.

I found that if I put 24:00 in a cell, `B1`, then the formula below works:
`=B1-A2`
but I'd like to have a formula without reference to another cell for the 24:00 constant? I guess there might be a way to express the constant of 24:00 as the duration in formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simply:

```
="24:00:00"-A1
```

[image: 0]

---

for ArrayFormula try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A; TEXT("24:00:00"-A1:A; "hh:mm"); ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Where can I find the documentation on such knowledge?

Comment: @YuShen not sure if there is any, tho